# Android - Can't load image from http

Tags: android, http, url

I need to load an image from http, and I'm using this code:

```
                        Bitmap bitmap;                        
                        InputStream is = null;
                        try {
                            is = (InputStream) new URL("www.TESTWEBSITE.com/TEST.JPG").getContent();
                        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }



                        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
```

But bitmap is still null.. Any help please ?

Comment: Did you give your app internet permissions in your manifest? Did you wrap your request in an AsyncTask or a separate thread?

Comment: this code is in my main activity. I've set this permission:  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: Use AsyncTask http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html

Comment: I can't belive that my question was downvoted... WHY ?? By the way thanks Spephan I'll give it a look

Comment: I'm not the one who downvoted your question, but I suppose someone downvoted your question because your question is a very common one on Stackoverflow. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668776/problem-loading-image-from-web-android?rq=1

Comment: At least I solved using AsyncTask ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update** : this is full snapshot performing what you want :

```
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL("www.TESTWEBSITE.com/TEST.JPG");
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream is = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
        }
```

Please, make sure to run it off UI thread, such as in AsyncTask as others have commented. You can try it in main thread for experimental purposes but be prepared for ANR.

Comment: @Luca What is the cause of the crash ? Moreover, this snapshot should be put on other thread as others pointed out, such as inside an AsyncTask. Let me know if you'd like to get more details on this.

Comment: @Luca Were you able to fetch Bitmap (non-null value) with the snapshot above ? If so, could I please ask you to accept the answer . Thnx

Comment: At the moment I'm not able, but I'm accepting your answer anyway. Because it looks like to be working.

Comment: @Luca Thnx. Feel free to follow up with questions in case of problem.