# Android load from URL to Bitmap #2

Tags: android, android-emulator, bitmap

I am having trouble loading a bitmap from a url on Android based on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8993175/1062794

I've simplified the case to the absolute minimum:

```
public void loadBitmap(View view) {
    Bitmap b = getBitmapFromURL("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/7/70/Example.png");
}

public Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(src);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        return myBitmap;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

I have enabled internet access in manifest (I believe):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

When I run the app it crashes with `null` details when it tries to run `connection.connect()`. Stepping through I see it tries to throw this error from `StrictMode.class`:

```
if ((mPolicyMask & PENALTY_DEATH_ON_NETWORK) != 0) {
    throw new NetworkOnMainThreadException();
}
```

This is my first day trying to make an Android app so I could be making an obvious mistake. I am using the emulator and Win7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting with Android 3.0, synchronous operations can no longer be run directly from a UI thread. If you try to call the loadBitmap(View view) method directly in your onCreate() method, your application will crash when it is run on a device running Android 3.0 and later. Because loadBitmap() method is synchronous - that is, it will not return control until the image is downloaded - calling it directly will freeze the UI of your activity. This is not allowed in Android 3.0 and later; all synchronous code **must** be wrapped using an *AsyncTask* class. Using AsyncTask enables you to perform background tasks in a separate thread and then return the result in a UI thread. That way, you can perform background operations without needing to handle complex threading issues. To call the loadBitamp() method **asynchronously**, you need to wrap the code in a subclass of the AsyncTask class, as shown here:

```
private class DownloadImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    protected Bitmap  doInBackground(String... urls) {
    return getBitmapFromUrl(urls[0]);
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitamp result) {
    ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
    img.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}
```

Now in the onCreate() method create a new instance of AsyncTask class and execute it:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    new DownloadImage().execute("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/7/70/Example.png");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

this is because you are trying to access the internet from the ui thread (more info [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html#AsyncTask)) .

create a new thread (you can use an asyncTask if you wish, but any other thread creation method would suffice) in order to access the internet , and once the bitmap is ready , pass it to the ui thread if you wish to show it

also , for a nice sample of bitmap handling read this :

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Your void will crash when image size big 5 MG. Bitmap are stacking RAM so sample 20 images * 5 = 100 mb. When you re open activity another 100 mb spend your RAM and app will crash. You add follow lines your code;

```
                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inPreferredConfig = Config.RGB_565;
                options.inSampleSize = 2;
                Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input,rect,options);
```