# share image with URL android share intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I need to know if it is possible to share an image using only its url with a share intent. Here is my code.

```
Intent imageIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
Uri imageUri = Uri.parse("http://eofdreams.com/data_images/dreams/face/face-03.jpg");
imageIntent.setType("image/*");
imageIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
startActivity(imageIntent);
```

So far its not working and I haven't found any helpful answers online. I would like to do this using the share intent and without downloading the image.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can share image using share intent, but you've to decode image to a localized Bitmap

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hey view/download this image");
String path = Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), loadedImage, "", null);
Uri screenshotUri = Uri.parse(path);

intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, screenshotUri);
intent.setType("image/*");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share image via..."));
```

`loadedImage` is the loaded bitmap from http://eofdreams.com/data_images/dreams/face/face-03.jpg

Comment: So there is no way of doing this without the bitmap?

Comment: Can my "loadedImage" be a string to a web URL?

Comment: Works like a charm !! :D

Comment: any possible direct sharing? without download image?

Comment: what about `loadedImage`? How can we load bitmap on it?

Comment: @inverted_index You can either use Glide or Picasso to do the heavy lifting, and get a bitmap from network or stored resource. 
For Glide: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-callbacks-simpletarget-and-viewtarget-for-custom-view-classes 

For Picasso: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20181491/use-picasso-to-get-a-callback-with-a-bitmap#answer-34390998

Comment: Thanks for the response, I've used Fresco library, but I'm not sure how to get bitmap of the image which is loaded by Fresco. do you have any ideas?

Comment: exactly what i needed!

Comment: @ShahidGhafoor  How do you convert image URL to a bitmap ? I searched on it and I found that , they use a HTTP connection but it cause `networkOnMainThreadException` .

Comment: @Ahmed try this
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8993175/4575105
or try using picasso 
http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: @ShahidGhafoor I solved it when I use `AsyncTask` to handle the `network main thread exception `

Comment: @Ahmed It's way more efficient and less time consuming, if you use Picasso or Glide to get the bitmap then using an `AsyncTask` and the above said libraries gracefully handles any OOM exceptions that might occur due to `Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);` if you try to decode a large stream.

Comment: @NitinMisra How can i share any kind of file from url instead of image

Answer (score 1):

See here [HERE](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Sharing-Content-with-Intents)

```
final ImageView imgview= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.feedImage1);

                Uri bmpUri = getLocalBitmapUri(imgview);
                if (bmpUri != null) {
                    // Construct a ShareIntent with link to image
                    Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
                    shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bmpUri);
                    shareIntent.setType("image/*");
                    // Launch sharing dialog for image
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share Image"));    
                } else {
                    // ...sharing failed, handle error
                }
```

then add this to your activity :

```
public Uri getLocalBitmapUri(ImageView imageView) {
    // Extract Bitmap from ImageView drawable
    Drawable drawable = imageView.getDrawable();
    Bitmap bmp = null;
    if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable){
       bmp = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    } else {
       return null;
    }
    // Store image to default external storage directory
    Uri bmpUri = null;
    try {
        File file =  new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(  
            Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "share_image_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
        out.close();
        bmpUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return bmpUri;
}
```

Comment: this is such redundant way to share image

Comment: And not what the OP is asking

Answer (score 0):

I've tried several methods, however non of them worked for me and the parts of the operations were unclear, so here is what I use for sharing image or video type content in case having the absolute path of the data.

In android **manifest.xml** add the following lines:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
//Other codes
<provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.example.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
</provider>
//Other codes
</application>
```

In the resource directory **res**, make a new folder called **xml**. Place a new file into it with the same name you used in the **manifest.xml** at the meta-data part, in this case **provider_paths.xml**:

> android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"

Place the following in it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path
        name="external_files"
        path="." />
    <root-path
        name="external_files"
        path="/storage/"/>
</paths>
```

In the activity you wish to use the share function, place the following code, where path is a string variable containing the absolute path of the content, and "com.example.fileprovider", the author value of Fileprovider is based on one of the line of the fresh xml file created above like this:

> android:authorities="com.example.fileprovider"

```
File file = new File(path);
//Checking if the file exists
if(file.exists()) {
    //Creating the Uri for the file using the provider we just created
    Uri contentUri = 
    FileProvider.getUriForFile(Gallery.this,"com.example.fileprovider", file);
    //Creating the share intent
    Intent S = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    //Allowing different types to be shared
    S.setType("*/*");                                        
    S.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    //Providing the uri to the intent
    S.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, contentUri);
    //Starting the intent, can choose from apps which are listening for the 
    //content type
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(S, "Share content using"));
}
else{                                  
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),path + " does not 
    exist",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

With this it is easy to share content from the device with the path of it.
The authorities and resource values are crucial in **manifest.xml**. One can change them of course, but then make sure to modify them at all occurances.

**Resources**:

[Android Share Intent Image Sharing not working Except WhatsApp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57045494/android-share-intent-image-sharing-not-working-except-whatsapp)

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-share-image-from-url-with-intent-in-android/

https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send

Answer (score -2):

convert url to string format

```
Intent imageIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
Uri imageUri = Uri.parse("http://eofdreams.com/data_images/dreams/face/face-03.jpg");
imageIntent.setType("image/*");
imageIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, String.valueOf(imageUri));
startActivity(imageIntent);
```

Answer (score -3):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

intent.setType("text/plain");

intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"http://eofdreams.com/data_images/dreams/face/face-03.jpg"); 

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share Image"));
```

Comment: I've marked up your answer as code so it's easier to read; but would you mind adding some explanation to it, so people can see more easily what your solution is and how it works?

Comment: this is just sending image link, not image itself

Comment: @HarpreetSingh Some app will Open Url into image some App will display only url only