# Share image puts path in to address

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm having this issue where sharing an image from my app to Gmail puts the path of the image in the To field.

Here's the code that I'm using:

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("image/*");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Beam Dental Insurance Card");
shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION); // temp permission for receiving app to read this file
shareIntent.setDataAndType(insuranceCardImageUri, getActivity().getContentResolver().getType(insuranceCardImageUri));
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, insuranceCardImageUri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share Insurance Card"));
```

And here's what I get.

[image]

The To: field gets filled in with the path to the image with the "content:" removed from the front. I've tried setting the `EXTRA_EMAIL` on the intent but that doesn't help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, replace:

```
shareIntent.setDataAndType(insuranceCardImageUri, getActivity().getContentResolver().getType(insuranceCardImageUri));
```

with:

```
shareIntent.setType(getActivity().getContentResolver().getType(insuranceCardImageUri));
```

as `ACTION_SEND` does not use a `Uri` in the data field of the `Intent`.

Then, remove:

```
shareIntent.setType("image/*");
```

as you do not need to call `setType()` twice (or even call `setType()` and `setDataAndType()`, as you have it here).

Also, bear in mind:

- If the `Uri` is not coming from your app (e.g., your own `ContentProvider`), third-party apps like Gmail may not be able to use it, as they may not have permission to access it. This is not significantly different than passing a URL to a third-party app, where the URL requires an authenticated user session to be useful.
- There is no requirement for `ACTION_SEND` implementations to honor *both* `EXTRA_STREAM` *and*EXTRA_TEXT`.

Answer (score 1):

You can share image using share intent, but you've to decode image to a localized Bitmap

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hey view/download this image");
String path = Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), loadedImage, "", null);
Uri screenshotUri = Uri.parse(path);

intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, screenshotUri);
intent.setType("image/*");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share image via..."));
```

`loadedImage` is the loaded bitmap from http://eofdreams.com/data_images/dreams/face/face-03.jpg

acoording to [Nitin Misra](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25136183/4427731)