# How to get Uri addresses of all the images in an array of drawables?

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-intent, uri

I have an array of drawables that i want to send via share intent.

```
  public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.drawable.ic_blue1,
        R.drawable.ic_blue2,
        R.drawable.ic_blue3,
        R.drawable.ic_blue4,
        R.drawable.ic_blue5,}
```

but share intent requires uris of all items that are being sent.How do i get uri of the items in this array?Is there a way to iterate through them and get uri?

Comment: `I have an array of drawables`. No you have an integer array.

Comment: Please show how you construct an uri for one of them. After that you can concentrate on having more than one.

Comment: `Is there a way to iterate through them`. Iterate through an integer array array? Any problem doing so?

Comment: Yes you are right.But Iterating through this is not an issue.Issue is getting uri address of all these resources dynamically,it would require iteration on items of array.To access items of an array we need to loop through them,and there should be a way to loop through these items and get there resource uri's dynamically.I am looking for that.

Comment: You are telleing nothing new. And you did not tell how tto get the uri for one of them.

Comment: I've worked on couple of solutions given here,they do generate uri but i am getting a different exception.But they do generate uri
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896223/how-to-get-an-uri-of-an-image-resource-in-android
However there is still no help if i want to loop over an array of drawables and get all there uri's at given time.

Comment: As said before: you have an array of integers. And why do you refuse to show the code for getting one uri? It's not that difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is already present in below URL
[share image with URL android share intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25135873/share-image-with-url-android-share-intent).

Solution is typically converting the drawable resource to bitmap.
Create ArrayList of Bitmaps.
You can add all the data to Parcelable Array.

```
List<Bitmap> bitmapArray = new ArrayList();
for(int i=0;i<mThumbIds.size();i++) {
    bitmapArray.add(getLocalBitmapURI(mThumbIds.get(i));
}
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("",bitmapArray);
```

Comment: Arrays' of bitmaps are dangerous, you could easily get an OOM error.

Comment: @Krishty I agree with you. If images of large I dont accept such a requirement for sharing images. If image size is small, then I am encouraged to design a solution.