# Is that UPI Deep Linking available for request money?

Tags: deep-linking, upi

I used upi deep url  `upi://pay?parm-name=param-value&param-name=pram-value&...`
in psp appliaction.I am looking for request url where merchant or customer can send request to another customer to pay.Like bhim app request money. Also i want know how do we share upi deep link url in whatsapp  or email

Comment: Have you find any way to achieve this?, I need same thing

Comment: Hi, did you get the solution? I'm also looking for the same. I'm using Ionic.

Answer (score 1):

For this you need to generate URI with your details like amount, your upi id, your name and you need 2 more parameters .i.e transaction id and transaction reference id.

Like example:

```
private String getUpiURL(String payeeAddress, String payeeName, String payeeMCC, String trxnID, String trxnRefId,
                        String trxnNote, String payeeAmount, String currencyCode, String refUrl) {
String UPI = "upi://pay?pa=" + payeeAddress + "&pn=" + payeeName
        + "&mc=" + payeeMCC + "&tid=" + trxnID + "&tr=" + trxnRefId
        + "&tn=" + trxnNote + "&am=" + payeeAmount + "&cu=" + currencyCode
        + "&url=" + refUrl;
return UPI.replace(" ", "+");
}
```

**First way** After that you can share this URL. it may be in the form of String URL or you can also share in QR Code format. it depend on your application logic.

How to share image or link For this you can check  this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/25136183/5275436

**Second Way** If you want in-app URL sharing or Payment request then you can use your server database structure and web logic. like Post request to customer and send notification for open this URL and Pay.

**Important**

Don't pass **mam** parameter in URL. This is for Minimum amount which provide editable mode.

As per the specification

> mam: This parameter is conditional and shall be used to define a
>   minimum amount rule where amount field in PSP app is editable. If mam
>   tag is not present or ‘mam=null’ or ‘mam=’ then amount field should
>   NOT be editable. Note: if a customer enters the value less than value
>   passed in mam then UPI will decline the transaction. To reduce such
>   declines PSP application should not allow entry of amount below mam
>   value

For more information about specification you can check this link
https://www.npci.org.in/sites/default/files/UPI%20Linking%20Specs_ver%201.6.pdf