# How to give unloaded imageview different colors until they are loaded, change Picasso code to glide

Tags: android, imageview, picasso, image-loading, android-glide

[image: this by picasso]

This easy to achieve using Picasso

```
 Picasso.with(holder.mImageView.getContext())
            .load(item.getUrl())
            .into(new Target() {
                @Override
                public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                    holder.mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    holder.mLoadingImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    holder.updatePalette();//the logic of generate diffrent background colors
                    Log.d(TAG, "on success");
                }

                @Override
                public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
                    holder.mLoadingImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    Log.d(TAG, "on error");
                }

                @Override
                public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
                    holder.mLoadingImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            });
```

and the `holder` take care of `that logic` (getting different colors for unloaded image) from `updatePalette` function, [here its code](https://github.com/lgvalle/RecyclerViewDemo/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/pruebas/lgvalle/mispruebas/DummyAdapter.java) or the [whole demo](https://github.com/lgvalle/RecyclerViewDemo) if you want

in glide what?

```
Glide.with(holder.mImageView.getContext())
            .load(item.getUrl())
            .into(/*WHAT*/);
```

Any duplication would help.

Comment: are you talking about placeholder image ?

Comment: yes with different color every time

Comment: different color every time means ? In each loading a different placeholder ?

Comment: Are you looking for this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27394016/how-does-one-use-glide-to-download-an-image-into-a-bitmap

Comment: @ShreeKrishna maybe yes ,, looks at the picture

Answer (score 3, accepted):

lastly I did it

```
    private ColorDrawable[] vibrantLightColorList =
        {
                new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#9ACCCD")), new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#8FD8A0")),
                new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#CBD890")), new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#DACC8F")),
                new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#D9A790")), new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#D18FD9")),
                new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#FF6772")), new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#DDFB5C"))
        };
```

then

```
Glide.with(holder.mImageView.getContext())
            .load(item.getUrl())
            .placeholder(getRandomDrawbleColor())
            .into(holder.mImageView);
```

and

```
public ColorDrawable getRandomDrawbleColor() {
    int idx = new Random().nextInt(vibrantLightColorList.length);
    return vibrantLightColorList[idx];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve the same using [Target](http://bumptech.github.io/glide/javadocs/latest/com/bumptech/glide/request/target/Target.html) or [SimpleTarget (implements Target)](http://bumptech.github.io/glide/javadocs/latest/com/bumptech/glide/request/target/SimpleTarget.html) in glide.

**i.e.**

```js
Glide.load("http://somefakeurl.com/fakeImage.jpeg")
      .asBitmap()
      .fitCenter()
      .into(new SimpleTarget(250, 250) {

          @Override
          public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation glideAnimation) {
              // Image Loaded successfully.
          }

          @Override
          public void onLoadStarted(Drawable placeholder){
            // Image Loading starts
          }


          @Override
          public void  onLoadFailed(Exception e, Drawable errorDrawable){
            // Image Loading failed
          }

      });
 }
```

Comment: can I create my own target ? how to create MyTarget? please update the question to explain what to do function that I'm not interested in

Answer (score 1):

Keep PlaceHolder Until The Image is Loading Using Picasso's placeholder function

```
Picasso.with(context)
            .load("image_url")
            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .into(imageView);
```

Comment: I need different `image color` for every image like the picture

Comment: you can not give color to image instead you can try applying other colored images...

Answer (score 0):

Methods of setting the placeholder Image are same in `Picasso` and `Glid`

**In Glid**

```
Glide.with(holder.mImageView.getContext())
            .load(item.getUrl())
            .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
            .into(imageView)
```

**In Picasso**

```
Picasso.with(holder.mImageView.getContext())
            .load(item.getUrl())
            .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
            .into(imageView)
```

Comment: the given image in placeholder will be fixed for all images

Comment: You can also change the colors or drawable randomly using random integer, or seperate the setting of placeholder method and change that dynamically in each position with conditions where ever you used the adapter...