# Glide error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException - You must call this method on a background thread

Tags: java, android, illegalargumentexception, android-glide

I'm using glide to load an image using its resource ID into a bitmap, and I want to pass the bitmap to a member function of a custom view class.

This is my code:

```
try {
         Bitmap bm=Glide.
                with(getApplicationContext()).
                load(mThumbIds[position]).
                asBitmap().
                into(width, height). // Width and height
                get();
        drawView.setImg(bm);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Whenever I try to run it I get the following error:

> Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{...}:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: YOu must call this method on a
>   background thread

How do I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does one use glide to download an image into a bitmap?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27394016/how-does-one-use-glide-to-download-an-image-into-a-bitmap)

Answer (score 0):

You can't call `get()` on the main thread because it performs a long running task and is likely to cause performance problems.

Instead, consider subclassing [`ImageViewTarget`](http://bumptech.github.io/glide/javadocs/latest/com/bumptech/glide/request/target/ImageViewTarget.html), or [`ViewTarget`](http://bumptech.github.io/glide/javadocs/latest/com/bumptech/glide/request/target/ViewTarget.html) and using `into()` instead of `get()`. `into()` will load the image asynchronously and you can use your custom subclass to call the appropriate member function in `onReasourceReady`.

Be sure to clear out your Bitmap (usually by passing `null` to the member function) when `onLoadFailed` or `onLoadCleared` are called.