# Is there a way to load image as bitmap to Glide

Tags: android, image-resizing, android-glide, image-scaling

Im looking for a way to use bitmap as input to Glide. I am even not sure if its possible. It's for resizing purposes. Glide has a good image enhancement with scale. The problem is that I have resources as bitmap already loaded to memory. The only solution I could find is to store images to temporary file and reload them back to Glide as inputStream/file..  Is there a better way to achieve that ?

Please before answering .. Im not talking about output from Glide.. `.asBitmap().get()` I know that.I need help with input.

Here is my workaround solution:

```
 Bitmap bitmapNew=null;
        try {
            //
            ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(ctx);
            File directory = cw.getDir("imageDir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            File file=new File(directory,"temp.jpg");
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, fos);
            fos.close();
            //
            bitmapNew = Glide
                    .with(ctx)
                    .load(file)
                    .asBitmap()
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
                    .skipMemoryCache(true)
                    .into( mActualWidth, mActualHeight - heightText)
                    .get();

            file.delete();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logcat.e( "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
        }
```

I'd like to avoid writing images to internal and load them again.That is the reason why Im asking if there is way to to have input as bitmap

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: I wrote that in question ... Scaling.. I didn't find better way to scale my images than Glide

Comment: But what exactly, whats your use case

Comment: I didn't -1, and no it's not clear cause you can scale and play with images in many ways depending on what you want to achieve

Comment: I tried tens of scaling methods .. the best is Glide.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

For version 4 you have to call `asBitmap()` before `load()`

```
GlideApp.with(itemView.getContext())
        .asBitmap()
        .load(data.getImageUrl())
        .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
            @Override
            public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {}
            });
        }
```

More info: http://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/targets.html

Comment: oh Glide, why change that and cause people to search for the error for hours :/

Comment: SimpleTarget is deprecated in latest version

Comment: I will accept this answer is it's up-to-dated code for on-going version .. thanks @teffi

Comment: Please consider this fix as base fix : https://stackoverflow.com/a/42278907/2267723 and this one is up-to-dated coding of it

Comment: What's `SimpleTarget`?

Comment: asBitmap should be after load method()

Comment: Replace SimpleTarget with CustomTarget and implement the remaining methods.

Comment: `SimpleTarget` is deprecated. Should be replaced with `CustomTarget` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41804371/1528805)

Answer (score 26):

This solution is working with Glide V4.
You can get the bitmap like this:

```
Bitmap bitmap = Glide
    .with(context)
    .asBitmap()
    .load(uri_File_String_Or_ResourceId)
    .submit()
    .get();
```

Note: this will block the current thread to load the image.

Comment: it is not working.... is there any other solution to get bitmap as output from byte[]

Comment: Works perfect on 2021.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. 95% of other answers were always for loading into an Imageview.

Answer (score 19):

A really strange case, but lets try to solve it. I'm using the old and not cool `Picasso`, but one day I'll give Glide a try. 
Here are some links that could help you :

- [Bitmap POC](https://gist.github.com/TWiStErRob/0b0b083225f2869b5cb1)
- [Supporting bitmaps topic](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/122)
- [Someone also facing your problem](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/458)

And actually a cruel but I think efficient way to solve this :

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  yourBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
  Glide.with(this)
      .load(stream.toByteArray())
      .asBitmap()
      .error(R.drawable.ic_thumb_placeholder)
      .transform(new CircleTransform(this))
      .into(imageview);
```

I'm not sure if this will help you, but I hope it can make you a step closer to the solution.

Comment: Just because of my interest, why are you facing such kind of issue? Can't you load your images directly with Glide from an url etc.?

Comment: "Efficient": I/O on UI thread? Compress just to decompress? Use the POC to squeeze it through the pipeline instead. Even just calling the transformation directly in the background while creating the image would be better.

Comment: @YuriiTsap I am making screen shots from bitmap of views in memory. These views are not just images..

Comment: @YuriiTsap I have case for your question. I using XML RPC odoo api which returns image in base64 json string format only.

Answer (score 13):

There is little changes according to latest version of `Glide`. Now we need to use `submit()` to load image as  bitmap, if you do not class `submit()` than listener won't be called.

here is working example i used today.

```
Glide.with(cxt)
  .asBitmap().load(imageUrl)
  .listener(new RequestListener<Bitmap>() {
      @Override
      public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object o, Target<Bitmap> target, boolean b) {
          Toast.makeText(cxt,getResources().getString(R.string.unexpected_error_occurred_try_again),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          return false;
      }

      @Override
      public boolean onResourceReady(Bitmap bitmap, Object o, Target<Bitmap> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean b) {
          zoomImage.setImage(ImageSource.bitmap(bitmap));
          return false;
      }
  }
).submit();
```

It is working and I'm getting bitmap from listener.

Answer (score 7):

Please use Implementation for that is:

> implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'

```
     Glide.with(this)
     .asBitmap()
      .load("http://url")
    .into(new CustomTarget <Bitmap>() {   
@Override  
public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, @Nullable Transition <? super Bitmap> transition) { 
                // you can do something with loaded bitmap here

 }
@Override 
public void onLoadCleared(@Nullable Drawable placeholder) { 
 } 
});
```

Answer (score 6):

Most of the API's and methods of Glide are now deprecated. 
Below is working for Glide 4.9 and upto Android 10.

For image URI

```
  Bitmap bitmap = Glide
    .with(context)
    .asBitmap()
    .load(image_uri_or_drawable_resource_or_file_path)
    .submit()
    .get();
```

Use Glide as below in build.gradle

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
```

Comment: This method returns error to run it into background thread.

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer works for previous versions, but in new versions of Glide use:

```
RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
requestOptions.placeholder(android.R.drawable.waiting);
requestOptions.error(R.drawable.waiting);
Glide.with(getActivity()).apply(requestOptions).load(imageUrl).into(imageView);
```

[Courtesy](http://RequestOptions%20requestOptions%20=%20new%20RequestOptions();%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20requestOptions.placeholder(android.R.drawable.waiting);%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20requestOptions.error(R.drawable.waiting);%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Glide.with(getActivity()).setDefaultRequestOptions(requestOptions).load(imageUrl).into(imageView);)

Comment: Don't use setDefaultRequestOptions for an individual request. It's only useful if you want to apply the same options across all requests in a particular Activity or Fragment. To apply options to a specific request, use .apply(RequestOptions): http://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/options.html#requestoptions

Answer (score 4):

here's another solution which return you a bitmap to set into your ImageView

```
Glide.with(this)
            .load(R.drawable.card_front)    // you can pass url too
            .asBitmap()
            .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                @Override
                public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation<? super Bitmap> glideAnimation) {
                    // you can do something with loaded bitmap here

                    imgView.setImageBitmap(resource);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me in recent version of Glide:

```
Glide.with(this)
        .load(bitmap)
        .dontTransform()
        .into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 2):

For what is is worth, based upon the posts above, my approach:

```
     Uri sArtworkUri = Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart");
Uri imageUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(sArtworkUri, String.valueOf(album_id));
```

then in the adapter:

```
        //  loading album cover using Glide library

    Glide.with(mContext)
            .asBitmap()
            .load(imageUri)
            .into(holder.thumbnail);
```

Answer (score 2):

## Updated answer 2022 Aug

```
Glide.with(context)
      .asBitmap()
      .load(uri) // Uri, String, File...
      .into(new CustomTarget<Bitmap>() {
          @Override
          public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
              useIt(resource);
          }

          @Override
          public void onLoadCleared(@Nullable Drawable placeholder) {
          }
      });
```

***onResourceReady*** : The method that will be called when the resource load has finished.
`resource` parameter is the loaded resource.

***onLoadCleared*** : A mandatory lifecycle callback that is called when a load is cancelled and its resources are freed. You must ensure that any current Drawable received in *onResourceReady* is no longer used before redrawing the container (usually a View) or changing its visibility.

`placeholder` parameter is the placeholder drawable to optionally show, or null.

Answer (score 1):

In Kotlin,

```
Glide.with(this)
            .asBitmap()
            .load("https://...")
            .addListener(object : RequestListener<Bitmap> {
                override fun onLoadFailed(
                    e: GlideException?,
                    model: Any?,
                    target: Target<Bitmap>?,
                    isFirstResource: Boolean
                ): Boolean {
                    Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "failed: " + e?.printStackTrace(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    return false
                }

                override fun onResourceReady(
                    resource: Bitmap?,
                    model: Any?,
                    target: Target<Bitmap>?,
                    dataSource: DataSource?,
                    isFirstResource: Boolean
                ): Boolean {
                    //image is ready, you can get bitmap here
                    return false
                }

            })
            .into(imageView)
```

Answer (score 1):

*For 2021 :*

```
  val bitmap=Glide.with(this).asBitmap().load(imageUri).submit().get()
```