# Can't change ImageView if Glide doesn't find URL

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, android-glide

I have a little problem using Glide. In my app I use Glide to show pictures from Firestore documents in an ImageView. This picture can be changed by the user if they tap on the ImageView.

This works perfectly except for one condition:
I have a field in my Firestore documents for the url but sometimes this field is an empty string (""). When it's empty, the *SetImageAsBitmap()* method (which I'm using to set and change pictures) doesn't work, it only shows the error image set in Glide.
When this field contains a valid link for the picture or I delete the whole Glide code snippet (see below) it changes perfectly.

```
Glide.with(getActivity())
.load(documentSnapshot.getString("jobPictureUrl"))
.fitCenter()
.error(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.photo))
.into(jobImage);
```

My guess is it's something about my Glide method, because the *SetImageAsBitmap()* works as needed. Thanks for your help!

Comment: you cant pass empty string as url to glide

Comment: That's why I added a default picture in '.error' :) But this doesn't help in my problem at all.

Comment: you can handle it like if imageurl is null or empty

Comment: Oh, I didn't think about it at all. Simple but effective solution. Thank you! :)

Comment: you might get your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42278134/is-there-a-way-to-load-image-as-bitmap-to-glide)