# Showing get() method not found

Tags: android, android-download-manager, android-wallpaper

I'm trying to set wallpaper by downloading an image from internet but it's showing that "get()method" is not found.
My Code:
In this code wall_set is a button's name

```
wall_set.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Bitmap result=Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
                            .load("http://www.sport-stickers.com/images/2013/CARTOON%20IRON%20ONS/Doraemon/Doraemon%20Iron%20ons%20(Wall%20Stickers)%20N3715.jpg").get();


                    WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
                    try {
                        wallpaperManager.setBitmap(result);
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
    );
```

Comment: Check out the [documentation for Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki). Looks like you should be using `into()` not `get()`.

Comment: It look like you are missing to add asBitmap() see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/27394484/7134908

Answer (score 1):

change this part of your code:

```
Bitmap result=Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
                        .load("http://www.sport-stickers.com/images/2013/CARTOON%20IRON%20ONS/Doraemon/Doraemon%20Iron%20ons%20(Wall%20Stickers)%20N3715.jpg").asBitmap().get();
```

add "asBitmap"

```
you might need to add  
asBitmap().into(20, 20). // Width and height
```

in the following

Comment: Thanks for ur response sir but even after adding ".asBitmap()" it's showing same error

Answer (score 0):

If you follow Glide sample usage it comes up with that get() method belongs to java.util.concurrent.Future object. And Future class definition is given by the official doc as below.

> `public interface Future<V>` A Future represents the result of an
>   asynchronous computation. Methods are provided to check if the
>   computation is complete, to wait for its completion, and to retrieve
>   the result of the computation. The result can only be retrieved using
>   method get when the computation has completed, blocking if necessary
>   until it is ready. Cancellation is performed by the cancel method.
>   Additional methods are provided to determine if the task completed
>   normally or was cancelled. Once a computation has completed, the
>   computation cannot be cancelled. If you would like to use a Future for
>   the sake of cancellability but not provide a usable result, you can
>   declare types of the form Future and return null as a result of the
>   underlying task.
>
> **Sample Usage** (Note that the following classes are all made-up.)
>
> ```
> interface ArchiveSearcher { String search(String target); }
>  class App {
>    ExecutorService executor = ...
>    ArchiveSearcher searcher = ...
>    void showSearch(final String target)
>        throws InterruptedException {
>      Future<String> future
>        = executor.submit(new Callable<String>() {
>          public String call() {
>              return searcher.search(target);
>          }});
>      displayOtherThings(); // do other things while searching
>      try {
>        displayText(future.get()); // use future
>      } catch (ExecutionException ex) { cleanup(); return; }
>    }
>  }
> ```

Lets see what happens step by step:

```
Bitmap theBitmap = Glide. 
        with(this). //in Glide class and returns RequestManager
        load(image_url). // in RequestManager and returns RequestBuilder<Drawable>
        asBitmap(). //in RequestBuilder and returns RequestBuilder<Bitmap>
        submit(). // in RequestBuilder and returns FutureTarget<TranscodeType> which extends Future<>
        get(); // this belongs to Future object which is the result of async computation

public static RequestManager with(Context context) {
    return getRetriever(context).get(context);
  }

public RequestBuilder<Drawable> load(@Nullable Object model) {
    return asDrawable().load(model);
  }


  public RequestBuilder<Bitmap> asBitmap() {
    return as(Bitmap.class).transition(new GenericTransitionOptions<Bitmap>())
            .apply(DECODE_TYPE_BITMAP);
  }

public FutureTarget<TranscodeType> submit() {
    return submit(Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL, Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL);
  }


public interface FutureTarget<R> extends Future<R>, Target<R> {
}
```

But more proper and secure solution is by using callback

```
Glide
    .with(this)
    .load(image_url)
    .asBitmap()
    .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>(100,100) {
        @Override
        public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation glideAnimation) {
            //resource is the resulting bitmap
        }
    });
```