# Can I load bitmap from firebase storage instead of loading it to image view?

Tags: android, firebase, bitmap, firebase-storage, android-glide

I want to use bitmap in my program without loading it to imageView but this glide function is not letting me do anything I want.

```
Glide.with(this /* context */)
        .using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
        .load(storageReference)
        .into(imageView);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does one use glide to download an image into a bitmap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27394016/how-does-one-use-glide-to-download-an-image-into-a-bitmap)

Comment: That post solved my problem but i am getting a problem. bitmap is loading after the view load. Can you help me how can I restrict my view that when bitmap is loaded view can load itself?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Glide
     .with(mContext)
     .load(URL)
     .asBitmap()       
     .error(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_placeholder))
     .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
     .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
            @Override
            public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation glideAnimation) {

                    // use your bitmap as you wish
                }
            });
```