# Draw a marker in Mapbox Android from a custom external image URL

Tags: android, image, icons, mapbox, marker

I am trying to figure a way to draw a marker in Mapbox Android SDK but all example show how to use a custom image from the DRAWABLE folder.

I would like to place a custom SVG icon from a custom URL. If not SVG at least PNG for transparency purposes.

Is it possible?

Examples that I found are similar to this one:

```
Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
    MainActivity.this.getResources(), R.drawable.custom_marker);
    mapboxMap.addImage(MARKER_IMAGE, icon);
```

Comment: Can you clarify which version you are using? The syntax has changed slightly in the latest semver release (7.0.0), so the answer to this question will depend on this.

Comment: We are using 6.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the caveat that in v7.0.0 you have the option to use the [Annotation Plugin](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/plugins/overview/annotation/), which provides a slightly more intuitive, object-oriented way to set up your icon/annotation layer, here's my recommended approach:

The code snippet you've posted is one part of the `Style -> Source -> Layer` flow used for runtime styling in Mapbox's SDK. For your purposes, especially if you're adding multiple markers to your map with the same icon, you should add your markers via a `SymbolLayer`. There's a working example of how the `SymbolLayer` syntax works [here](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/symbol-layer-info-window/) (it also includes some code for adding interactivity to your markers). You can also get some quick boilerplate code over at Mapbox's [marker playground](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/interactive-tools/marker-playground/).

**To answer your primary question:** the SDK doesn't include any convenience methods for loading an external SVG or PNG directly as a SymbolLayer's iconImage, so you'll need to use a library like [Glide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27394016/how-does-one-use-glide-to-download-an-image-into-a-bitmap) or [Picasso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20181491/use-picasso-to-get-a-callback-with-a-bitmap) to retrieve the image and convert it to a bitmap before passing it to `mapboxMap.addImage()`.

Comment: It's also worth noting that direct URL support is being debated as a possible feature for Mapbox's GL JS library (see option `B)` on this GitHub ticket: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/7587). If adopted by the GL JS team, this feature would likely be added to the roadmap for the native SDKs.

Comment: mapboxMap doesn't has an addImage on android. you need to add the image through the style style.addImage(string, bitmap)

Comment: @riastrad do we have this feature added for native SDK yet ?

Comment: @HussnainAzam I'm no longer with Mapbox, so not as up to date on the latest SDK updates. However, from a quick glance at the latest SDK's API docs, I don't believe it has been. Feel free to reach out to the company's support team to confirm: https://www.mapbox.com/support/