# Glide image from gallery to bitmap variable

Tags: android, android-glide

I have a variable `Bitmap image`. I have `imageButton` in my fragment. I can change image of `imageButton` with `Glide.with().load().into()`. But I want not to just change image but to save it into `Bitmap` variable so I can use it for some other task. I tried this

```
Bitmap image = Glide.with(getContext()).asBitmap().load(imagePath).submit().get();
imageButton.setImageBitmap(image);
```

But image of imageButton does not change. What's wrong with first line then? Because I am pretty sure that problem is there but don't understand yet what is exactly wrong.

---

A solution is to do

```
Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.
        decodeStream(getContext().
        getContentResolver().
        openInputStream(selectedImage));
imageButton.setImageBitmap(image);
```

Where `selectedImage` is `Uri selectedImage = data.getData()` of `onActivityResult` method, but it will be total mess because of size of bitmap, so we have to use `createScaledBitmap`, I don't like it. For some reason `Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath)` doesn't work, imageButton just becomes tiny grey square, and I didn't find a solution for this.

Comment: Have you tried specifying the size in your `submit(...)` function? Also, what version of Glide are you using?

Comment: @C.Ar. `submit` thingie didn't work. Glide version is 4.10

Comment: It could be just a problem with Glide. Refer to other people's solutions here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27394016/how-does-one-use-glide-to-download-an-image-into-a-bitmap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you should even think about doing this in some serious project but for now it did what needs to be done for me. Earlier I declared `private Bitmap jopa`.

```
Glide.with(getContext()).asBitmap().
        load(selectedImage).override(500,500).
        into(new CustomTarget<Bitmap>() 
        {
         @Override
         public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
             imgShare.setImageBitmap(resource);
             jopa = ((BitmapDrawable)imgShare.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
         }

         @Override
         public void onLoadCleared(@Nullable Drawable placeholder) {

         }
     });
```

Now `Bitmap jopa` can be used for other tasks. I hope. Tested it to change picture of another imageview, it worked, so I'll pray it will work further. Full `onActivityResult` code [here](https://pastebin.com/yQSPVdRM). Don't want question to get too messy

Answer (score 0):

first of all why are using the imageButton..use imageView it will good than 
imagebutton and it will work