# Is there a way to get Image asset for app(made in android studio) from online or somewhere else

Tags: android

how can I get image asset(from online or somewhere else) so that i can insert an image in my android app using android studio?

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27394016/how-does-one-use-glide-to-download-an-image-into-a-bitmap

Answer (score 0):

Using Image library is easy way. (like Glide, Picasso, etc.)

for example. (using Glide)

```
    String imageUrl = "https://img1.daumcdn.net/thumb/R1280x0/?scode=mtistory&fname=https://k.kakaocdn.net/dn/EShJF/btquPLT192D/SRxSvXqcWjHRTju3kHcOQK/img.png";
    Glide.with(this).load(imageUrl).into(ivImage);
```

it make image from url.

Plus. how you can use Glide

1. Add the dependencies in build.gradle(app)

   dependencies {
     implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
     annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'
   }

and use it.

more info is [here](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/)

Comment: But I don't have any knowledge about Glide, Picasso,etc. Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: @ArijitPaul, no other easier ways than loading images with libraries (eg. Glide, Picasso)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do would be to use third party image libraries like Glide, Picasso, etc.
Here is how you can easily do it using `Glide`

**Add the dependencies in build.gradle(app)**

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
  annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'
}
```

**Using Glide to fetch the images**

```
ImageView targetImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);  
String internetUrl = "http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png";

Glide  
    .with(context)
    .load(internetUrl)
    .into(targetImageView);
```

You can refer to [this](https://blog.mindorks.com/downloading-and-showing-image-with-glide-library-in-android) tutorial for more