# How to load images from URL with Android Studio?

Tags: java, android-studio

I cannot load images to my app. I tried with vanilla Android Studio Java and with Picasso, nothing happens:

```xml
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/activity_main_icon"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="308dp"/>
```

```java
private ImageView icon;
icon = findViewById(R.id.activity_main_icon);
```

With

```
URL u = new URL("http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/" + i + ".png");                          
icon.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(u.openConnection().getInputStream()))
```

or

```
String iconUrl = "http://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + i + ".png";
Picasso.get().load(iconUrl).into(icon);
```

I checked the url it is ok.

It may be the declaration of the image in my activity, but I followed the documentation.

Comment: You should try to use https instead of http. It is just a shot, because could be an issue with the image, or your internet connection, your hardware, etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does one use glide to download an image into a bitmap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27394016/how-does-one-use-glide-to-download-an-image-into-a-bitmap)

Comment: What's the value of `i`? I am getting a 404 on browser when I tried https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/1.png (tried 0, 1, 2) as well. Or maybe I don't have access to it :)