# Simple Android Image Download Async

Tags: java, android, json, asynchronous, android-volley

I'm attempting to obtain an image URL through JSON data, which works successfully.  Everything below works SLOWLY.  However, I am trying to figure out a way to get a URL to display much faster below in Android Volley or another fast method.  I am trying to download these images from a URL (resized too) into a `MapView` pin icon.  If there is a more efficient example anyone can find, I am all in.  Please let me know if you need more information from me.  I am following this guide: [Android load from URL to Bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8992964/android-load-from-url-to-bitmap)

```
final String profilePicture = profilePic;

URL url = new URL(profilePicture);
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.connect();
InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
Bitmap bit = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bit, 100, 100, false);

ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 10, out);
Bitmap decoded = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray()));


bitmapDescriptor = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(decoded);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use picasso library :

http://square.github.io/picasso/

Its easy to use and have alot of useful feature !
For example :

```
Picasso.with(context)
  .load(url)
  .resize(50, 50)
  .centerCrop()
  .into(imageView)
```

Comment: Your solution will not work in this case because it wont run in the context and it needs to assign the image to the bitmapDescriptor.

Comment: I am following this guide: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8992964/android-load-from-url-to-bitmap

Comment: Can you somehow convert this to work with a bitmapDescriptor like above?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Koushik Ion library. Its very easy to use.

[https://github.com/koush/ion][1]