# Android - how to convert image url to image?

Tags: android, json, android-activity, android-asynctask

I am getting json response which includes image string also. How to decode the image and how to set in ImageView?

```
{
success: true
customer: {
customer_id: 93
firstname: "vigneshtesting"
lastname: ""
email: "testing@gmail.com"
telephone: 8189968996
fax: ""
image: "images/89159094355efdcebb3c568.81451258.jpg"
salt: "222ef72b3"
password: "8e61e0255f99ede9c2eb2290347285c5a6552012"
newsletter: ""
customer_group_id: ""
status: ""
date_modified: "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
abbr: ""
grpname: ""
description: ""
approve: ""
disp_comp: ""
comp_no: ""
disp_tax: ""
tax_id: ""
sortorder: ""
banip: ""
}
}
```

Comment: 1. Parse your json and get the url. 2. Download the image and set the image to imageview

Comment: @vignesh Use Image loading libraries like `Glide`, `Universal Image Loader` etc.,

Comment: I will do..@Raghunandan @b1izzard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to parse the JSON.

```
JSONObject jsonObject = <your-object>;
String image = jsonObject.getString("image");
```

Now you have the image url as a string in the string object 'image'. You have to load the image in this url to the target imageview. For that you can use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/). A clear description of how to use that is mentioned there. You can directly use this string for that purpose as shown below.

```
Picasso.with(context).load(image).into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 2):

Parse the image url from json and get the image as bitmap:

```
URL url = new URL("http://....");
Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
```

Then set the image in imageview as:

```
imageview.setImageBitmap(image);
```

Note:use a asynctask to download the image from the url.

Comment: Give the full path of the image nad not just images/89159094355efdcebb3c568.81451258.jpg,it will work definitely

Answer (score 1):

Parse your json to get image url.
To show image from url
best way is to use [Picasso library](https://github.com/square/picasso)
In which you can directly put your image Url and it also help to cache the image.

Read this [Documentation](http://square.github.io/picasso/) for picasso.

Other helpful libraries are:

1) [Android-Universal-Image-Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

2) [ion](https://github.com/koush/ion)

**Or** if you want to get bitmap from url then see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8992964/android-load-from-url-to-bitmap)

Answer (score 1):

Parse your JSON and get the url and use any library to download like : Picaso library

[here is good tutorial](http://square.github.io/picasso/)