# Download an image into Bitmap file in android

Tags: java, android, bitmap, download, httpurlconnection

I've been trying to download an image into a bitmap element to load them into a gridView with images, but I need to do it async because if not gives the error "android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException".

Searching I found a lot of tutorials to do that, but all of them add this element to an ImageView when finished. 
Is there any way to do that but into a Bitmap?

Here I have ways to download without async that I found:

```
URL url = new URL("http://....");
Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
```

One more:

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(src);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        return myBitmap;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

[Android load from URL to Bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8992964/android-load-from-url-to-bitmap)

Comment: Put one of your code snippets in a thread to perform that work asynchronously.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean.. I'm new in Java

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/creating-and-starting-threads.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your `getBitmapFromURL` method into an `AsyncTask`, see below:

```
private class GetBitmapFromURLAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>   {
    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        return getBitmapFromURL(params[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
    }
}
```

Nest the above `AsyncTask` into your Activity:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
  // To store the Bitmap returned by doInBackground asynctask
  private Bitmap result;
  // existing Activity code
  ...

  private class GetBitmapFromURLAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>   {
    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
      return getBitmapFromURL(params[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
      //  return the bitmap by doInBackground and store in result
      result = bitmap;
    }
}
```

And to call the above code:

```
GetBitmapFromURLAsync getBitmapFromURLAsync = new GetBitmapFromURLAsync();
getBitmapFromURLAsync.execute("http://....");
```

Comment: But how can I do to return the bitmap?

Comment: I have added code to the answer on how to return the Bitmap

Answer (score 0):

You can't make heavy operations like http request from main (UI) thread in android. Or you will get that error. You can use [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

```
class ImageDownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>   {

    //this operation is in backgrouund
    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        return getBitmapFromURL(params[0]);
    }

    //operation is finished, update the UI with bitmap
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
    }
}
```

Or just use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) library, it does all work for you, including caching.

```
Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);
```