# Setting an overall timeout for a bitmap fetch and decode operation using HttpURLConnection and BitmapFactory

Tags: android, bitmap, android-asynctask, httpurlconnection

I'm using an HttpURLConnection to fetch a bitmap from a specified URL using the method as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8993175/4070848), the code for which is copied below for convenience:

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(src);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        return myBitmap;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Log exception
        return null;
    }
}
```

I need the whole fetch and decode process to finish within a specific time, because I'm running it from a BroadcastReceiver (albeit within an AsyncTask to keep it off the UI thread).  Therefore the whole receiver operation must be finished within 10 seconds to avoid being killed mid-way, so I want to allow the bitmap fetch and decode, say, 5 seconds.

I suppose that I'll be advised not to attempt it this way, and instead use an IntentService or something, but nonetheless I wonder whether it's possible to avoid that just by ensuring the AsyncTask fetch is completed quickly (even if that is by way of a timeout).

I'm aware that I can set the following timeouts on `connection`:

```
connection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
connection.setReadTimeout(5000);
```

But my understanding is that the connect timeout just puts a limit on how long it takes to connect, while the read timeout does so in respect of how long it takes to *start* reading the data.

But, neither of these puts a limit on the whole process: connect, read, decode.

I guess part of my uncertainty is over when the data is actually read... is it when you call `connection.connect()` or is it when you call `connection.getInputStream()` or is it only when you call `BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input)`?

If the data is only read when you call `decodeStream()` then how do you put a timeout on that?

Maybe I need to set an overarching timer, and close things down gracefully when that fires, rather than trying to rely on an HttpURLConnection-related timeout?