# getting images from internet and store them in internal memory dynamicly in Android

Tags: android, image, dynamic, gallery, imageswitcher

I have an Activity which is used as an image gallery and works quite well. But it loads images from integer array which has references from drawables. And what I want to do is getting images from internet and store them in internal memory then use them in my gallery.

Here is my code below. Any help will be appreciated.

```
import okan.apps.tabbar.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ImageSwitcher;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ViewSwitcher.ViewFactory;

 public class Activities extends Activity implements ViewFactory {

ImageSwitcher imageSwitcher ;

Integer[] imageList = {
        R.drawable.gallery,
        R.drawable.menu,
        R.drawable.promotion,
        R.drawable.info,
        R.drawable.activities       
};

int curIndex=0;
int downX,upX;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
     setContentView(R.layout.activities_main);

     imageSwitcher = (ImageSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.imageSwitcher);
     imageSwitcher.setFactory(this);
     imageSwitcher.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,android.R.anim.fade_in));
     imageSwitcher.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,android.R.anim.fade_out));

     imageSwitcher.setImageResource(imageList[curIndex]);
     imageSwitcher.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
     public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

         if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
             downX = (int) event.getX(); 
             Log.i("event.getX()", " downX " + downX);
             return true;
         } 

         else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
             upX = (int) event.getX(); 
             Log.i("event.getX()", " upX " + downX);
             if (upX - downX > 100) {

                 //curIndex  current image index in array viewed by user
                 curIndex--;
                 if (curIndex < 0) {
                     curIndex = imageList.length-1;
                 }

                 imageSwitcher.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(Activities.this,R.anim.slide_in_left));
                 imageSwitcher.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(Activities.this,R.anim.slide_out_right));

                 imageSwitcher.setImageResource(imageList[curIndex]);
                 //GalleryActivity.this.setTitle(curIndex);
             } 

             else if (downX - upX > -100) {

                 curIndex++;
                 if (curIndex > 4) {
                     curIndex = 0;
                 }

                 imageSwitcher.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(Activities.this,R.anim.slide_in_right));
                 imageSwitcher.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(Activities.this,R.anim.slide_out_left));

                 imageSwitcher.setImageResource(imageList[curIndex]);
                 //GalleryActivity.this.setTitle(curIndex);
             }
                 return true;
             }
             return false;
         }
     });
}
public View makeView() {
    ImageView i = new ImageView(this);  
    i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
    return i;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something like https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader . Or you can check the code in https://github.com/cyrilmottier/GreenDroid . Personally I liked the first one since it was focused only on image loading.

Comment: These are quite complex for the thing I want to do. Basicly, giving image pathes from internal memory instead of giving references to my interger array from drawable will be enough. I can handle rest of it.

Comment: so if I can understand you correctly you cannot refer to your images that are downloaded from internet as the images that are in your resources. therefore instead of using an int[] array you have to use a drawable or bitmap array. use setImageBitmap (or it was smth similar) to set the image of the imageview.

Comment: to convert a url content into image please either check those library codes or things like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090650/android-loading-an-image-from-the-web-with-asynctask. you have to download the image in a background thread and call the ui change (setImageBitmap) in the main thread.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Siyamed, I will try those and give a feed back as soon as possible for the solution I found.

Comment: The example that you suggested works with image view and I have ImageSwitcher. I couldnt find a way to work around of it.