# How to download images in background in Android GridView?

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-gridview

I have this GridView in android in which I display some images that should be downloaded on-demand. The problem is taht the program waits upon every image request to be downloaded completely and then moves on to the next image thus making the loading very slow. I just want to know how should I move the image downloading to the background and display the image when it's ready.
I think I should use AsyncTask for this purpose but I have no idea how should I do this?

Comment: Yes, use AsyncTask. Google it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android : Loading an image from the Web with Asynctask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090650/android-loading-an-image-from-the-web-with-asynctask)