# Any faster way to load imaeview with url

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-imageview

I load image within imageview using

```
 try {
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new java.net.URL(SplashItems.get(position).get("imageUrl")).getContent());
                 ImageViewObject.setImageBitmap(bitmap); 

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

but it's so so slow, any faster way to do that

Best regards

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using `AsyncTask` to load. This way your app with still run, and the user can interface while the image loads. I have also found that it cuts the download time by quite a bit because the downloading is done on a background thread and is able to focus on that. Here is a link to help you get started:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

This article also talks about handlers, which may also be of some use to you.

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html

Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can  have a look at class [ImageDownloader](http://code.google.com/p/googletv-video-player/source/browse/src/com/example/tv/videoplayer/ImageDownloader.java?r=c5ce73eef28e2b59891ce43af8fb668d5af0f85b) in `GoogleTV` sample. They use asynctask do download image in background and implement a cache to improve performance. Another tutorial from Android developer blog [Multithreading For Performance](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html)

And  similar question on SO : [Loading an image from the Web with Asynctask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090650/android-loading-an-image-from-the-web-with-asynctask). 
 The last is [UrlImageViewHelper](https://github.com/koush/UrlImageViewHelper). You can check the performance and choose the best. I myself often use `ImageDownloader`