# load image to custom ArrayAdapter

Tags: java, android

i tring load images and texts to a ListView using a arrayAdapter custom but the load image fail

here are my arrayAdapter

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Post> {

    private ImageTask image;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Post> posts) {
        super(context, 0, posts);
    }

     @Override
     public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Get the data item for this position
        Post post = getItem(position);    
        // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
        if (convertView == null) {
           convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.post_list, parent, false);
        }
        // Lookup view for data population
        TextView tituloView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.titulo);
        TextView subtituloView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.subTitulo);
        ImageView fotoView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        TextView textoView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.texto);


        // Populate the data into the template view using the data object
        tituloView.setText(post.post_titulo);
        subtituloView.setText(post.post_sub_titulo);
        //this like idk if are the way corret for load the image into ViewImage specific
        new ImageTask(fotoView).execute("http://java.sogeti.nl/JavaBlog/wp-content/uploads/2009/04/android_icon_256.png");

        textoView.setText(post.post_texto);
        // Return the completed view to render on screen
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

here a ImageTask image

```
public class ImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    ImageView bmImage;

    public ImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mIcon11;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}
```

and here the call from MainActivity

```
// Create the adapter to convert the array to views
CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, arrayOfPost);
// Attach the adapter to a ListView
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvUsers);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

the arrayOfPost is coming of a parse jonson to a ArrayList and links images is contained there, but in this example i using images from google developer

and the xml used by array adapter here

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/titulo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/subTitulo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/texto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
</LinearLayout>
```

any know which are my wrong and how i should to do for load images?
i dont right if is the way corret for load the image in the specific ViewImage
//this lines are in fist class posted

```
new ImageTask(fotoView).execute("http://java.sogeti.nl/JavaBlog/wp-content/uploads/2009/04/android_icon_256.png");
```

Comment: the image dont apear into device, just the texts

Comment: you should add this to the question.

Comment: ok, already and add the xml too

Comment: I mean you should describe the fail/error you met in the question.

Comment: Do you have the `INTERNET` permission? Also, there are libraries for this, like [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) or [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide).

Comment: y already use the permission, how now i just want teaching android, will let library to after, but keep in mind libraries win time in development;)

Comment: i post the line that i think are my wrong, but yet dont find the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steps to load an image in an AsyncTask

Step 1:

```
ImageView fotoView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
```

Step 2:

```
String URL1 = "http://java.sogeti.nl/JavaBlog/wp-content/uploads/2009/04/android_icon_256.png";
```

Step 3:

```
fotoView.setTag(URL1);
new DownloadImageTask.execute(fotoView);
```

Step 4:

```
public class DownloadImagesTask extends AsyncTask<ImageView, Void, Bitmap> {

ImageView imageView = null;

@Override
protected Bitmap doInBackground(ImageView... imageViews) {
    this.imageView = imageViews[0];
    return download_Image((String)imageView.getTag());
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
    imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
}

private Bitmap download_Image(String url) {

    Bitmap bmp =null;
    try{
        URL ulrn = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)ulrn.openConnection();
        InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
        if (null != bmp)
            return bmp;

        }catch(Exception e){}
    return bmp;
} }
```

Reference:[Android : Loading an image from the Web with Asynctask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090650/android-loading-an-image-from-the-web-with-asynctask)

Answer (score 1):

I see there're few things which can be improved in your code:

1. in your custom adapter you should use `ViewHolder` to improve your `ListView` performance because those lines: `convertView.findViewById()` cost too much.

2. You use `AsyncTask` to load your Image from the Internet in `GetView()`. It is ok but whenever you scroll your `ListView`, your `GetView()` is called and you start another `AsyncTask`. There's no guarantee that which `Task` will finished first, so your image position in `ListView` maybe wrong (now you load same image in every row, it's not happen, but in the future it will).

 Therefore, my suggestion is: use `ViewHolder` in your adapter, use some 3rd party `Lib` to load image efficiently such as [Universal ImageLoader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

Comment: really work and happen what u tell, really load slow :), now will look for libs ty for tips :)