# Loading images in ImageView from a url

Tags: android, imageview

I found this snippet on the internet:

```
try{
        URL url = new URL(imgUrl+imageId[position]+".png");
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    }catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

The code doesn't give me any errors,I am getting the exact url I want. But the ImageView stays empty. Running the debugger I got no problem upto: `InputStream is = con.getInputStream();`
After this the debugger goes to the catch block, and debugger window shows

```
NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

I know it's because I am doing network operations on the UI thread , but my activity already is extending another class, so I can't extend AsycnTask. Any workaround for this?

Plus: If there is an exception, shouldn't the app crash? My app runs fine, but the imageview doesn't show anything.

Comment: start using Picasso.

Comment: Try this

Android : Loading an image from the Web with Asynctask


http://stackoverflow.com/a/3090802/4826114

Comment: Your class dont need to extend AsyncTask, create a class which extends AyncTask<...> the in doInBackground(...) of that write your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Picasso that will help you also in async thread:

```
Picasso.with(context).load(imgUrl+imageId[position]+".png").into(imageView);
```

You can download the source here: http://square.github.io/picasso/
or add it as dependency directly from Android Studio

Comment: will this line of code ensure the image loading is done in a separate thread?

Comment: yes , picasso handle all background threads

Comment: @AmanGrover Absolutely yes.

Comment: Yes. Picasso handles image loading for you in separated thread and resize the result (to get rid of OutOfMemory exception) then set the bitmap to your ImageView on UIThread

Answer (score 1):

Newer versions of Android requires you to make HTTP requests (networking) on a separate thread. You can create a separate Thread, or use AsyncTask for this. The same code should work after you do this.