# Picasso not showing images

Tags: android, imageview, picasso

I have an app that gets images from internal storage, and must show them in an ImageView. Since the loading of the images has an impact in performance in the app, I would like to do it asynchronously. I made [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31700716/new-thread-while-loading-listview-in-a-fragment) question, and was told to use Picasso. The app now goes fast, but is not showing the image. This is the code I am using to put the image in the ImageView:

```
Picasso.with(c).load(path).resize(dpToPx(80), dpToPx(80)).centerCrop().into(holder.foto);
```

This is the adapter, with the commented lines I used without Picasso. That way, the Image is shown, but it delays the UI:

```
public class FotoAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private ArrayList<BeanFotos> fotos;
    private LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    Context c;
    Handler handler;

    public FotoAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<BeanFotos> fotos){
        this.fotos=fotos;
        inflater=LayoutInflater.from(c);
        this.c=c;

    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if(fotos!=null){
            return fotos.size();
        }
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {

        return fotos.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {


            convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.foto_layout, null);
            holder=new ViewHolder();
            holder.lat=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textlat);
            holder.lon=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textlon);
            holder.foto=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.foto);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

                String path=fotos.get(position).getFotoPath();
                Picasso.with(c).load(path).resize(dpToPx(80), dpToPx(80)).centerCrop().into(holder.foto);
                /*Bitmap foto= BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
                int bmWidth=foto.getHeight();
                int bmHeight=foto.getHeight();
                int ivWidth;
                int ivHeigth;
                int new_width;
                int new_height;
                ivWidth=dpToPx(80);
                new_width=ivWidth;
                new_height = (int) Math.floor((double) bmHeight *( (double) new_width / (double) bmWidth));
                Bitmap newbitMap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(foto, new_width, new_height, true);*/
                holder.lat.setText(fotos.get(position).getLatitud().toString());
                holder.lon.setText(fotos.get(position).getLongitud().toString());
                //holder.foto.setImageBitmap(newbitMap);

        return convertView;
    }

    private int dpToPx(int dp)
    {
        float density = c.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        return Math.round((float)dp * density);
    }
    static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView lat;
        public TextView lon;
        public ImageView foto;
    }
}
```

Would be great to use Picasso and show the Image, but if that is not possible, what could I do?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this for:

**fetching from internal storage**

```
Picasso.with(c).load(new File(path)).resize(dpToPx(80), dpToPx(80)).centerCrop().into(holder.foto);
```

**loading from url**

```
Picasso.with(c).load(path).resize(dpToPx(80), dpToPx(80)).centerCrop().into(holder.foto);
```

Comment: Thanks dude, that was a life saver.

Answer (score 1):

You should parse path to uri then load the image as

```
pathUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(path));
Picasso.with(c).load(pathUri).resize(dpToPx(80), dpToPx(80)).centerCrop().into(holder.foto);
```