# Image download from URL

Tags: android

I'm learning Android Programming and what's mistake?

```
ImageView im = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
try {
     URL  u = new URL("http");
     HttpURLConnection ur = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
     InputStream in = ur.getInputStream();
     Bitmap bs = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);

     im.setImageBitmap(bs);

     in.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this. Most likely, you will find that you are crashing with a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/how-to-fix-android-os-networkonmainthreadexception

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3090802/5915572

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't run on main Thread, just use new Thread:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
        try 
        {
            //Your code goes here
        } 
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});

thread.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you search about [Picasso library](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.picasso/picasso)?

With picasso you can bind a bitmap from image request on your View(ie. ImageView). Doesn't matter how it works.

```
Picasso.with(context)
        .load(imageUri)
        .into(viewToAttach);
```

You can catch errors like Timeout or error response, with callbacks.

Comment: yes i know this library  but i want use my code thanks