# UI Freezes when Executing AsyncTask

Tags: android, user-interface, android-studio, android-asynctask

I'm downloading an image from sever using AsyncTask
but when calling `downloadImage()` from activity `onCreate()` the activity freezes til AsyncTask finishes downloading the image.

I'm using this code:

```java
  Bitmap downloadImage() {
        ImageDownloader task = new ImageDownloader();
        Bitmap myImage;

        try {
            myImage = task.execute("https://drive.google.com/uc?id=0B51TujFYa0RBUUYzSE15WHZRR3c").get();

            downloadedImg.setImageBitmap(myImage);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.i("Interaction", "Button Tapped");

        return myImage
   }



    public class ImageDownloader extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.connect();

                InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
                //to convert Image from string data to bitmap
                Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);

                return myBitmap;

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't properly use the *AysncTask* class. By calling `get()`, you pause your main thread until the image is downloaded. That's why the UI feels slow.

Instead, you should set the image from the task's `onPostExecute` method:

```
private Toolbar toolbar;
private ImageView downloadedImg;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // ... omitted ...

    ImageDownloader task = new ImageDownloader();    
    task.execute("https://drive.google.com/uc?id=0B51TujFYa0RBUUYzSE15WHZRR3c");

}

// ... omitted ...    

public class ImageDownloader extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();

            InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
            //to convert Image from string data to bitmap
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);

            return myBitmap;

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {

        downloadedImg.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've to do this asynchronously and NOT in the main activity, otherwise the page will be blocked until the download is complete. There is many options to do this. I think the best as indicated in the accepted answer of this question:

[Android : Loading an image from the Web with Asynctask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090650/android-loading-an-image-from-the-web-with-asynctask)

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the documentation for async task, you will find that `get()` has the following description

> Waits if necessary for the computation to complete, and then retrieves its result.

Instead of calling `get()` you should implement [onPostExecute](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute(Result)) in your AsyncTask subclass and deal with your image there. There is even an example on the android developer page.

```
public class ImageDownloader extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
   <...>

   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
      downloadedImg.setImageBitmap(result);
   }
}
```