# Android load image from URL into Bitmap object

Tags: android, image, bitmap

I'm trying to load an image from URL into Bitmap object, but I always end up with NetworkInUIThread kind of exception. Can anyone provide me a library for this?

Note, that I'm not trying to put the image into ImageView, I want to put it into Bitmap object first, as it will be used more times later in my app.

I found this code in some other StackOverflow thread, but it doesn't work.

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src){
    try{
        URL url = new URL(src);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        return myBitmap;
    }catch(IOException e){
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android : Loading an image from the Web with Asynctask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090650/android-loading-an-image-from-the-web-with-asynctask)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I fix android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/how-do-i-fix-android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

Comment: At first try to read about `NetworkOnMainThreadException` this will facilitate development

Answer (score 2):

Put this code inside the `doInBackground` method of an `AsyncTask`

e.g.

```
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            return myBitmap;
        } catch(IOException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
         //do what you want with your bitmap result on the UI thread
    }

}
```

and call it in your activity by:

```
new MyAsyncTask().execute(src);
```

Comment: This would work, but I need to get the Bitmap result object in my activity.

Comment: That’s what you have to do in the onPostExecute... create the MyAsyncTask as inner class inside your activity. read a AsyncTask tutorial for more

Answer (score 1):

```
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://....");
        Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
    } catch(IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        InputStream iStream = null;
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(5000 /* milliseconds */);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(7000 /* milliseconds */);
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.connect();
        iStream = conn.getInputStream();
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(iStream);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Glide To download image from server and store it in Bitmap Object.

```
Bitmap theBitmap = Glide.
    with(this).
    load("http://....").
    asBitmap().
    into(100, 100). // Width and height
    get();
```

Please Refer this to add glide dependency in your app -> https://github.com/bumptech/glide

Comment: Cannot resolve method 'asBitmap' using most recent Glide

Comment: I don't want the image to load in ImageView